# How to get a polygon from boost::geometry::model::polygon?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-geometry

I'm trying to calculate a difference of two polygons using `boost::geometry::difference` with `boost::geometry::model::polygon` representing my polygons.

In case when the first polygon contains the second one result of the operation is a single `boost::geometry::model::polygon` with the inner and outer rings populated with coordinates of the source polygons.

How do I get a polygon ([in the elementary geometry sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon)) from `boost::geometry::model::polygon`?

**Clarification:**

> In elementary geometry, a polygon is a plane figure that is bounded by a finite chain of straight line segments closing in a loop to form a closed chain or circuit.

The outer ring of `boost::geometry::model::polygon` is a polygon, the inner rings are polygons too. As a whole `boost::geometry::model::polygon` is not a polygon.

So, what I'm asking: How to convert `boost::geometry::model::polygon` to a *normal* polygon (having a single chain of straight line segments), which represents the same area on a plane.

**Here's what I'm trying to achieve:**

```
polygon1   = (0,0), (0,8), (8,8), (8,0), (0,0)
polygon2   = (2,2), (2,6), (6,6), (6,2), (2,2)
```

Polygons 1 & 2 in green / oker: [image]

```
difference = (0,0), (0,4), (2,4), (2,2), (6,2), (6,6), (2,6), (2,4), (0,4), (0,8), (8,8), (8,0), (0,0)
```

Expected difference in grey: [image]

I know the same `boost::geometry::model::polygon` having inner rings could be represented by infinitely many different *normal* polygons. I don't care which one I get.

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? You already have an object that represents a polygon, what is the other form of polygon that you want to acquire and what are you really trying to achieve? Maybe you want to plot the polygon?

Comment: Re. your edit "I know the same boost::geometry::model::polygon having inner rings could be represented by infinitely many different normal polygons. I don't care which one I get." - it seems that this precisely contrary to your real demands: you seem to care a lot. This is simply true because the one outer-ring with one or more inner rings **cannot** possibly be represented as "a normal polygon¹" in another way. (¹your definition: "(having a single chain of straight line segments)")

Comment: As you can see in my example, to represent the difference of two polygons I've introduced a straight line segment (0,4)-(2,4) creating [a weakly simple polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_polygon#Weakly_simple_polygon), obviously any other straight line segment connecting inner and outer boundaries could be used instead, thus resulting in infinitely many solutions to such a difference. And the definition is not _mine_, it's from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon).

Comment: I think I've understood your approach. I wouldn't say the results you expect would be topologically/mathematically equivalent, but I do see how they can be thought as _pragmatically_ equivalent. I'll post a stab at a custom algorithm shortly.

Comment: Thanks for the illustrations, though it looks like `polygon1` is rendered as a square with side of 10 instead of 8.

Comment: This might be of interest https://github.com/ivanfratric/polypartition/blob/master/src/polypartition.cpp#L174

Answer (score 1):

You can easily construct a ring that models your expected *weak simple polygon*. First:

#### Caveat

Note though that the result isn't valid for further use with the Boost Geometry library's algorithms.

Take your literal example:

```
std::string reason;
poly expected;
bg::read_wkt("POLYGON((0 0, 0 4, 2 4, 2 2, 6 2, 6 6, 2 6, 2 4, 0 4, 0 8, 8 8, 8 0, 0 0))", expected);
bool ok = bg::is_valid(expected, reason);
std::cout << "Expected: " << bg::dsv(expected) << (ok?" valid":" invalid: '" + reason + "'") << "\n";
```

Prints

> Expected: (((0, 0), (0, 4), (2, 4), (2, 2), (6, 2), (6, 6), (2, 6), (2, 4), (0, 4), (0, 8), (8, 8), (8, 0), (0, 0))) invalid: 'Geometry has invalid self-intersections. A self-intersection point was found at (0, 4); method: t; operations: x/u; segment IDs {source, multi, ring, segment}: {0, -1, -1, 0}/{0, -1, -1, 7}'

#### Algorithm implementation

With that out of the way, here's a simple algorithm to construct the simple weak polygon from a given polygon:

```
ring weak_simple_ring(poly& p) {
    ring r = p.outer();

    for (auto& i: p.inners()) {
        auto last = r.back();
        r.insert(r.end(), i.rbegin(), i.rend());
        r.insert(r.end(), last);
    }

    return r;
}
```

The only subtler point there is to reverse the direction (CW/CCW) of the inner rings to match that of the outer ring.

The algorithm doesn't attempt to be smart about finding a cut-point to the inner ring, which probably also means that it won't work nicely for the generic case with multiple inner rings.

### DEMO

Here's a full live demo

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7ef8064ea2a9640f)</kbd>**

Where the input is [image]

```
bg::read_wkt("POLYGON((0 0,0 10,10 10,10 0,0 0))", a);
bg::read_wkt("POLYGON((2 2, 2 6, 6 6, 6 2, 2 2))", b);
```

The transformation is

```
std::vector<poly> output;
bg::difference(a, b, output);

for (auto& p : output) {
    ring r = weak_simple_ring(p);
    bg::convert(r, p);
}
```

And the result becomes [image]

### More complicated sample

Consider when `b` had a hole: [image]

```
bg::read_wkt("POLYGON((0 0,0 10,10 10,10 0,0 0))", a);
bg::read_wkt("POLYGON((2 2, 2 6, 6 6, 6 2, 2 2)(3 3, 5 3, 5 5, 3 5, 3 3))", b);
```

The output with the same code becomes  [image]

Comment: Yeah, I've already had a similar solution in mind. Unfortunately it doesn't work in general: there could be other "holes" between the selected vertices, or a different order of vertices (see [modified demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e3d871ead5f8a77d)). I know the problem could be solved by searching for the closest pair of vertices and integrating one inner ring at a time, though I had hopes for a more performant algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

> *This is the old answer. After edits to the question I've posted [a simple implementation of an algorithm that suits the sample given](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37104653/85371)*

It already is.

If you mean, a "simple" non-holey polygon, the outer ring is all you want. Just discard the inner rings.

However, in the most generic case you can end up with multiple entirely disjunct polygons, which is why [the output is a collection of polygons](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms/difference.html). You will have to consider this possibility too (optionally joining the different result polygons into one and discarding inner rings if that's what you desire, functionally).

A sample:

```
bg::read_wkt("POLYGON((0 0,0 10,10 10,10 0,0 0))", a);
bg::read_wkt("POLYGON((2 -2,2 12,5 12,5 -2,2 -2))", b);
```

Here, `b` cuts `a` into two separate pieces. So you must be prepared to handle multiple, disjunct, output polygons:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/85ae091ad99498be)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/polygon.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/io/io.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

namespace bg = boost::geometry;
using pt   = bg::model::d2::point_xy<int>;
using poly = bg::model::polygon<pt>;

int main() {
    poly a, b;
    bg::read_wkt("POLYGON((0 0,0 10,10 10,10 0,0 0))", a);
    bg::read_wkt("POLYGON((2 -2,2 12,5 12,5 -2,2 -2))", b);

    std::cout << bg::dsv(a) << "\n";
    std::cout << bg::dsv(b) << "\n";

    {
        std::ofstream svg("/tmp/input.svg");
        boost::geometry::svg_mapper<pt> mapper(svg, 400, 400);
        mapper.add(a);
        mapper.add(b);

        mapper.map(a, "fill-opacity:0.5;fill:rgb(153,204,0);stroke:rgb(153,204,0);stroke-width:2");
        mapper.map(b, "fill-opacity:0.5;fill:rgb(204,153,0);stroke:rgb(202,153,0);stroke-width:2");
    }

    std::vector<poly> output;
    bg::difference(a, b, output);
    for (auto& p : output)
        std::cout << "\n\t" << bg::dsv(p);

    {
        std::ofstream svg("/tmp/output.svg");
        boost::geometry::svg_mapper<pt> mapper(svg, 400, 400);
        assert(output.size() == 2);
        mapper.add(output[0]);
        mapper.add(output[1]);
        mapper.add(b);

        mapper.map(output[0], "fill-opacity:0.5;fill:rgb(153,204,0);stroke:rgb(153,204,0);stroke-width:2");
        mapper.map(output[1], "fill-opacity:0.5;fill:rgb(153,204,0);stroke:rgb(153,204,0);stroke-width:2");
        mapper.map(b, "fill-opacity:0.15;fill:rgb(153,153,153);stroke-width:0");
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
(((0, 0), (0, 10), (10, 10), (10, 0), (0, 0)))
(((2, -2), (2, 12), (5, 12), (5, -2), (2, -2)))

    (((5, 10), (10, 10), (10, 0), (5, 0), (5, 10)))
    (((2, 10), (2, 0), (0, 0), (0, 10), (2, 10)))
```

SVGs rendered:

[image]

Comment: My whole point of using `boost::geometry::difference` was to exclude the area represented by the second polygon, therefor there's no point for me to discard inner rings. And yes I'm aware the result could be a list of polygons, I'm perfectly fine with it.

Comment: All I can say is that perhaps your questions should have been a bit clearer (as clear as my sample, for example). That would prevent quite a bit of wasted time.

Comment: Sorry, I though a _polygon in the elementary geometry sense_ would be clear enough.